# Does charity received cancel out charity given?

Tags: tzedakah-charity

In my community there is a big benefactor who provides tuition assistance for the Jewish day school.

A parent is in the practice of trying to give $2,000 a year to tzedakka but he receives $8,000 x 3 children in tuition assistance from the benefactor.

Ought he use the $2000 toward education and only accept $8000 x 3 -$2000 from the benefactor?

Answer (score 3):

Rambam says in [הלכות מתנות עניים פרק ז](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7207.htm):

> ואפילו עני המתפרנס מן הצדקה, חייב ליתן צדקה לאחר.
>
> Even a poor person who lives off charity is obligated to give charity to others. (translation mine)

It would seem that the parent should continue as they are doing, giving their $2000, even if that means accepting the full tuition assistance.

Comment: So would it make a difference if the parent gave $100 to tzedakka and accepted $8000 x3 - 1900?

Comment: I'm not a rabbi, but my understanding is that giving more is better. If the tuition fund is $8000, it makes sense to accept that, and then give whatever other tzedaka one can.